# Appending missing values in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list which looks like this:

```
[
{
    "timeline": "2014-10", 
    "total_prescriptions": 17
}, 
{
    "timeline": "2014-11", 
    "total_prescriptions": 14
}, 
{
    "timeline": "2014-12", 
    "total_prescriptions": 8
{
    "timeline": "2015-1", 
    "total_prescriptions": 4
}, 
{
    "timeline": "2015-3", 
    "total_prescriptions": 10
}, 
{
    "timeline": "2015-4", 
    "total_prescriptions": 3
} 
]
```

This is basically the output of a raw SQL query in Django which does a count of the total_prescriptions per months and arranges the data in ascending order.However,the nature of MYSQL count is that it does not return a 0 for null values.Hence,the month of February is totally skipped rather than having an entry with total_prescriptions equal to 0.

I plan to iterate through the list in python and manually add total_prescriptions=0 for all the missing months so that the output looks like this:

```
[
{
    "timeline": "2014-10", 
    "total_prescriptions": 17
}, 
{
    "timeline": "2014-11", 
    "total_prescriptions": 14
}, 
{
    "timeline": "2014-12", 
    "total_prescriptions": 8
{
    "timeline": "2015-1", 
    "total_prescriptions": 4
}, 
{
    "timeline": "2015-2", 
    "total_prescriptions": 0
}, 
{
    "timeline": "2015-3", 
    "total_prescriptions": 10
}, 
{
    "timeline": "2015-4", 
    "total_prescriptions": 3
} 
]
```

How would I go about doing that ?

Comment: when did i say that i have a dict of dicts ?

Comment: oh..sorry..corrected..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Pandas to solve this as it is obviously much faster for larger datasets and accomplishes this in a nice elegant way.
This is called "Resampling" in Pandas; first convert the your time to a numpy datetime and set as your index:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(L) #where L is my list of dictionaries
>>> df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.timeline,format='%Y-%m')
>>> df
timeline    timeline            total_prescriptions                            
2014-10-01  2014-10                   17
2014-11-01  2014-11                   14
2014-12-01  2014-12                    8
2015-01-01  2015-1                     4
2015-03-01  2015-3                    10
2015-04-01  2015-4                     3
```

Then you can add in the missing months with resample('MS')and use fillna(0) to convert null values to zero :

```
>>> df = df.resample('MS').fillna(0)
>>> df         
timeline                total_prescriptions
2014-10-01                   17
2014-11-01                   14
2014-12-01                    8
2015-01-01                    4
2015-02-01                    0
2015-03-01                   10
2015-04-01                    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could utilize `COALESCE` to return 0 when there are `NULL` values.

Comment: tried coalesce but it looks like it does not even return a NULL value..it just completely omits the row..did not work..

Answer (score 1):

Keep a reference list of known month numbers, and get a list of all the elements in the reference that do not exist in the pulled data.  In the code below, dc is your list of dicts.

```
ref = [str(x) + '-' + str(i) for x in range(min_year, max_year+1) for i in range(1,13)]
missing_timelines = [r for r in ref if r not in [i['timeline'] for i in dc]]
for m in missing_timelines:
  dc.append({"timeline": m, "total_prescriptions": 0})
```

Mic4ael's idea is good too.  Ideally you would handle this in the database.

Comment: the problem is that year range is not fixed..it is not only from 2014 to 2016..it could be any two years

Comment: But its always two?  Does it have to be two? Can it be 4?

Comment: yes..it all depends on the start and end date in the query..if the query says from 2009 to 2015..it will pull up the total prescriptions for all the months from 2009 to 2015..so it could be any number of years..but it is always arranged in ascending order by date if that helps

Comment: Replace 2014 and 2016 with min_year and max_year + 1.  Male sure those values get saved off to variables and passed to the function that fixes the db return data.

Comment: saarrr..this was nice..but i ended up using Pandas..Pandas turned out to be faster and has timeline samping which was just perfect for my needs..

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the efficiency of this code but this might help you.
**Try this:**

```
presub = {...}
before = int(presub[0]["timeline"].split("-")[1])
for x in presub:
  year = int(presub[x]["timeline"].split("-")[0])
  month = int(presub[x]["timeline"].split("-")[1])
  if before+1 != month:
    if before+1%12 != 0:
      year = year+1
    presub.append({"timeline":str(year)+"-"+str((before+1) % 12, "total_prescriptions":0)})

presub = sorted(presub, key=lambda k: k['timeline'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed my approach. The list you are starting with is `my_list`

```
def getDate(entry):
    """
    Given a list entry dict, return a tuple of ints:
    (year, month)
    """
    date = entry['timeline']
    i = date.index('-')
    month = int(date[i + 1:])
    year = int(date[:4])
    return (year, month)

def supplyMissing(year, month, n):
    """
    Given a year, month, & number of missing entries (ints),
    return a list of entries (dicts)
    """
    entries = []
    for e in range(n):
        if month == 12:
            year += 1
            month = 1
        else:
            month += 1
        entries.append({'timeline': str(year) + '-' + str(month),
                        'total_prescriptions': 0})
    return entries

# Make a copy of the list to work with:
new_list = list(my_list)

# Track the number of times corrections are made
c_count = 0

# Iterate over the list
for i in range(len(my_list) - 1):
    entry = my_list[i]
    next_entry = my_list[i + 1]
    year, month = getDate(entry)
    next_year, next_month = getDate(next_entry)

    if ((next_year == year and next_month == month + 1) or
        (next_year == year + 1 and next_month == month - 11)):
        pass
    # If entries are not sequential, determine what to add.
    else:
        # How many months are missing?
        if next_year == year:
            missing_months = next_month - month - 1
        else:
            dif_years = next_year - year
            missing_months = 12 * dif_years + next_month - month - 1

        # Generate missing entries
        missing_entries = supplyMissing(year, month, missing_months)

        # Insert missing entries into the temporary list.
        for m in range(missing_months):
            new_list.insert(i + 1 + m + c_count, missing_entries[m])
        c_count += 1

# Finalize the result
my_list = new_list
```

Comment: can't assume the start and end years to be 2014 and 2015..could be any two years..

Comment: Changed approach to work with any list regardless of start/end dates.